# Very strange GetOpenFileName problem

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I seem to be having a very strange problem with GetOpenFileName.

It errors for no apparent reason, however, if I call `CommDlgExtendedError()` in the error check, the error never happens in the first place.

Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    OPENFILENAME fm;
    char flnm[MAX_PATH];
    ZeroMemory(&fm, sizeof(fm));

    fm.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    fm.hwndOwner = NULL;
    fm.lpstrFilter = "Text Files (*.txt)\0*.txt\0";
    fm.lpstrFile = flnm;
    fm.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    fm.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
    fm.lpstrDefExt = "";

    if(!GetOpenFileNameA(&fm))
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "failed! :(", NULL, NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What's shown? "failed! :("

If I remove this check, I do see a file dialog. However, it doesn't work, and the filename box is pre-filled with random junk.

If I change to:

```
if(!GetOpenFileNameA(&fm))
{
    DWORD dwErr = CommDlgExtendedError();
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "failed! :(", NULL, NULL);
}
```

"failed! :(" is NOT shown. The file dialog shows and performs without issue.

What is going on!?!?

Comment: I haven't looked at your code, but when changing memory layout fixes bugs, that usually means bugs like bad pointers or overruns

Comment: That's probably because `fm` is filled with junk.

Comment: Since you don't seem to be editing this into a better question I'm going to give you a big hint instead of the answer: `fm.lpstrFile` must be null terminated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
OPENFILENAME fm;
char flnm[MAX_PATH]; // nobody initialized me ...
ZeroMemory(&fm, sizeof(fm));

fm.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
fm.hwndOwner = NULL;
fm.lpstrFilter = "Text Files (*.txt)\0*.txt\0";
fm.lpstrFile = flnm; // ... who knows what I am?
fm.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
fm.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
fm.lpstrDefExt = "";

if(!GetOpenFileNameA(&fm))
{
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "failed! :(", NULL, NULL);
}
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646839%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for `lpstrFile` states:

> The file name used to initialize the File Name edit control. The first character of this buffer must be NULL if initialization is not necessary. When the GetOpenFileName or GetSaveFileName function returns successfully, this buffer contains the drive designator, path, file name, and extension of the selected file.

You are not initializing `flnm` and therein lies the problem. You can solve the problem by writing `flnm[0] = '\0'` before you call `GetOpenFileName`.